# VBA to refresh link from Access tables to Excel Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an Access 2010 database that uses 5 tables linked to 5 Excel 2010 workbooks.

The table names match the workbook names (e.g. `My_Data1` table linked to `My_Data1.xlsx`). This database and linked workbooks need to be distributed to mulitple users, but the file path will be the same on each machine (for example `C:\Users\Public\MyDataFiles\`).

I want to ensure that the links to the Excel workbooks are established/refreshed once the files have been placed on each individual's machine with little or no user interaction. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A link will be refreshed - or rather re-read - whenever the linked table is opened, so no user interaction is needed.